# about Func<TElement, bool> predicate

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
//my question is here
public static Query Where<TElement>(this Query query, Func<TElement, bool> predicate) 
{
     query.sql +=" FROM Table WHERE "+ predicate+";"; 
     return query; 
} 

//Query class 
public class Query 
{
     public Query(){}
     public Query(string sql){this.sql = sql;} 
     public string sql { set; get; } 
}

//User class 
public class User 
{ 
     public int ID { get; set; } 
     public string Name { get; set; } 
} 

//example: 
User user = new User() { ID=1,Name="test"}; 
Query query = new Query(); 
query = query.Where<User>(u=>u.ID==user.ID); 
Console.WriteLine(query.sql);
```

After running, the result is:

```
FROM Table WHERE System.Func'2[DAL.User,System.Boolean]';
```

But what I need is:

```
FROM Table WHERE ID=1;
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: could you explain where this part comes in? `u=>u.ID==user.ID`. you only want to give the ID if it matches, otherwise what do you want?

Comment: First off, it will have to be of type `Expression<Func<TElement, bool>>` if you want to parse the predicate, my next question is what is your intended goal with this?  If you are using Linq To Sql like the question tag states why are you reinventing `Where`?

Comment: i want to know how the linq do

Comment: *facepalm*. drjchina, I think you're hunting lions before learning to hunt rabbits. There are many building blocks required to implement the LINQ2[X] packages. Perhaps you could start by understanding what blocks are used, and how they work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to learn about how Linq to Sql works to build up a sql query your first step will be to learn about [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).

The next step will be to gain some familiarity with [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) which will help out on how you can visit each piece in an expression tree.

From there read through the blog series ["LINQ: Building an IQueryable provider series"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx) as it goes through on how to parse an expression tree into sql.

The post ["Where and reusable Expression tree visitor"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/31/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-ii.aspx) will help out on how to parse your predicate.

Now since you will not be working with `IQueryable<T>.Where()` but just `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` not everything in these posts will relate completely but should be a good start to how to parse a predicate expression into a valid sql where clause.

Hope this can get you started!

Comment: Your references are way better than mine.  Questioner, follow these links instead!

Comment: do you think a link to Edulinq would be useful here? It describes Linq2Objects, but will still give a great overview of how Linq, in general, is implemented. http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx I didn't want to write a new question just to add that, but feel free to edit it into your answer if you deem it useful. Cheer

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to make your Query class LINQ-accessible, here.  When you participate in a LINQ Where clause, the predicate you get is a function object, not a string.  The idea is that you apply the predicate function to each of the elements that you enumerate, and yield-return only those for which the function returns "true."

LINQ-to-SQL looks at the code inside a predicate like this, which it presumes to be an expression (e.g., a lambda) that it can analyze and translate into a SQL expression.  Remember, a C# lambda can be generated by the compiler into either a delegate or an expression tree (see [this MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)), depending on the type expected in the expression it's in.  So LINQ-to-SQL is doing a lot of work, in other words, to turn that predicate into something it can run against the database engine.

If you're really going LINQ, you'll probably have to just get all records in your query and then just filter them using the predicate, unless this represents a scaling issue (depends on how serious your app is).  Also, a you'll have to write a proper Where function, which returns an IEnumerable object and uses yield-return.  See [this tutorial page](http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/02/17/Implement-Linq-to-Objects-in-CSharp-2) (you'll have to scroll down quite a bit) or read the LINQ chapters in the excellent C# in a Nutshell book.

On the other hand, if you don't actually care about LINQ and this code is just coincidentally LINQ-y, then just change your argument type to string and put quotes around the expression you want to use.